# What is the reverse of echo -e?

Tags: shell, echo

If I have a string with nonprintable characters, new lines, or tabs, is there a way I can use `echo` to print this string and show codes for these characters (e.g., `\n` for new line, `\b` for backspace)?

Comment: you can use printf command, see man printf

Comment: `e- ohce` \*rimshot\*

Comment: `printf '%q' "$str"` will print the string escaped. I'm not adding this as an answer since it's not the same form of escaping that `echo -e` uses -- rather, it's intended to be eval-safe -- but (1) it's good enough if your goal is human readability, (2) it's good enough if your goal is safe shell generation, and (3) `echo -e` is Evil And Wrong anyhow (if you read the POSIX spec, you'll see that printf is the preferred way to do string formatting, and `echo -e` is not guaranteed by baseline POSIX at all).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this. The most portable two that I know of are `sed` and `od` - they're both POSIX.

```
printf '\n\r\b\t\033[01;31m' | sed -n l
```

It does like... `read` style escapes - C-style.

#### OUTPUT

```
$
\r\b\t\033[01;31m$
```

`od` is a little more configurable...

```
printf '\n\r\b\t\033[01;31m' |
od -v -w12 -t c -t a -A n

 \n  \r  \b  \t 033   [   0   1   ;   3   1   m
 nl  cr  bs  ht esc   [   0   1   ;   3   1   m
```

If you wanna know what all of those options do you can look in `man od`, but I specify I want two types of escapes - the `-t c` backslash escapes and the `-t a` named characters.
The `-w` option used above is not POSIX-specified.

And here's a little shell function that will portably print out the octal values of each byte in its arguments - which, of course, `od` might handle as well with `-t o`:

```sh
proctal() (LC_ALL=C
    for a do while [ -n "$a" ] 
    do printf %o\\n "'$a"
    a=${a#?}; done; done)
```

That's a simple one. This is a little more complicated. It should be able to do what the shell-specific `printf -q` implementations can, though.

```sh
bsq() (set -f; export LC_ALL=C IFS=\'
    for a do q=${a##*\'}; printf \'
    [ -n "${a#"$q"}" ] &&
        printf "%s'\''" ${a%\'*}
    printf "%s'\n'''''\n" "$q"; done |
    sed -n "/'''''"'/!H;1h;//!d;$!n;x;l' |
    sed -e :n -e '/\\$/N;s/.\n//;tn
        s/\([^\\]\\\(\\\\\)*\)\([0-9]\)/\10\3/g
        s/\\\\'"''/\\\\''"'/g;s/$$//'
)
```

Using out example string from earlier with a little additional:

```sh
bsq "$(printf '\n\r\'\''b\t\033[01;31m')"
```

#### OUTPUT

```sh
'\n\r\\'\''b\t\0033[01;31m'
```

It's only slightly different. You might notice there's an extra `0` and an extra `\b`ackslash. This is to allow for easy translation to a `read` or a `%b` `printf` argument. For example:

```sh
i=0
until [ $((i=$i+1)) -gt 5 ]
do touch "\%$i$(printf 'hey\b \t;\n\033 ')"
done   #just for ugly's sake

bsq * | eval "
    printf '<%b>\n' $(tr \\n \ )
" | tee /dev/fd/2 |
sed -n l
```

#### OUTPUT

```sh
<\%1he  ;
>
<\%2he  ;
>
<\%3he  ;
>
<\%4he  ;
>
<\%5he  ;
>
<\\%1hey\b \t;$
\033 >$
<\\%2hey\b \t;$
\033 >$
<\\%3hey\b \t;$
\033 >$
<\\%4hey\b \t;$
\033 >$
<\\%5hey\b \t;$
\033 >$
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas It will *still* only do single-byte chars, but hopefully its less likely to screw up now.

Comment: Let me get you to the 10k mark :)

Comment: Woohoo!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @slm - let me guess.. You really liked the `proctal`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - do you have any thoughts on `bsq()` - is it missing anything? I ask because I'm not entirely confident about the backslashes.

Comment: @BinaryZebra - are the colors better? how do they differ?

Comment: @BinaryZebra - i dont care either way, and was merely curious if it was useful. seems to be the same - the syntax coloring here is crazy. for handling code interpreted in quotes *(like `eval "command $(##...some long arg parser function)"`* i often wind up doing stuff like `"command $(#fu"!ing colors)"`

Answer (score 12):

When you remove the `-e` switch to `echo`, in `bash`, and provided the `xpg_echo` option has not been enabled, it should print the strings as nothing more than their original text. So `\n` and `\t` would show up as literally that.

#### Example

```
$ echo "hi\t\tbye\n\n"
hi\t\tbye\n\n

$ echo -e "hi\t\tbye\n\n"
hi      bye
```

You can also use the `printf` built-in command of `ksh93`, `zsh` or `bash` to finagle this as well.

```
$ printf "%q\n" "$(echo -e "hi\t\tbye\n\nbye")"
$'hi\t\tbye\n\nbye'
```

(`bash` output shown above. There are some variations depending on the shell).

*excerpt from `help printf`* in `bash`

> `%q`    quote the argument in a way that can be reused as shell input

Comment: It's not `printf %q` that's truncating the trailing `\n`s, it's the `$()` output capture that strips them out.

Comment: @ecatmur - thanks I wrote that late at night and hadn't tried to debug it further. You'd be correct, it's the subshell that's stripping them off. Here's a reason why: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17747/why-does-shell-command-substitution-gobble-up-a-trailing-newline-char

Comment: ...anyhow, running `printf` inside of a subshell to capture its output is silly, since `printf -v varname` will put the output _directly_ into a variable, no subshell involved.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I'm not following you, I'm not running `printf` in a subshell, I was running `echo` in one, purely to demonstrate that you can take the special character output from `echo` and convert it back to the escaped notation.

Comment: @slm, that was a response to the first comment (well, the code that the first comment responded to), not the code as I found it now. If I inferred something inaccurate about prior edit state, my apologies.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - not an issue, was just trying to understand what you were pointing out 8-)

Answer (score 5):

You could use something like,

```
$ cat filename
Ramesh is testing
New Line        is
```

Now, you could do something like,

```
$ cat -A filename
```

**Output**

```
Ramesh is testing$
New Line ^Iis $
```

Another general testing without any files is as,

```
$ echo Hello$'\t'world. | cat -A
```

The above command yields the output as,

```
Hello^Iworld.$
```

**References**

- [Linux: Display / Show File Contents (tabs, line breaks, non-printing characters)](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2011/linux-display-show-file-contents-tabs-line-breaks-non-printing-characters/)

Comment: Or, in non-GNU implementations of cat, e.g. MacOS/X, take your cat to the vet ... **cat -vet**

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`, there are the `(q)`, `(qq)`, `(qqq)`, `(qqqq)` variable expansion flags that can *quote* the variables in various ways:

```
$ a=$'a b\nba\bc\u00e9\0'

$ printf '%s\n' $a
a b
bcé

$ printf %s $a | od -vtc
0000000   a       b  \n   b   a  \b   c 303 251  \0
0000013

$ printf '%s\n' ${(q)a}
a\ b$'\n'ba$'\b'cé$'\0'

$ printf '%s\n' ${(qq)a}
'a b
bcé'

$ printf '%s\n' ${(qqq)a}
"a b
bcé"

$ printf '%s\n' ${(qqqq)a}
$'a b\nba\bcé\0'

$ (){local LC_ALL=C; print -r -- ${(qqqq)a}}
$'a b\nba\bc\303\251\0'
```

In your case, you'd probably want one of the last two.

Answer (score 1):

`od -c` will print normal characters normally, but special characters (tab, newline, etc.) and unprintable characters as their `printf` escape code.

So:

```
$ echo -e asdf\\nghjk\\003foo | od -c -An
   a   s   d   f  \n   g   h   j   k 003   f   o   o  \n
```

The `-An` tells `od` to not output the address.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `printf` command. For example:

`printf "Hello\nthis is my line`

will output

```
Hello
this is my line
```

Comment: This is the *same* as `echo -e`, I'm looking for the *reverse*.

Comment: can you give me specific example?