# Bash String Expansion Corrupt

Tags: bash, string

I have the following:

```
echo "PLATFORM = $PLATFORM"
DATE_STRING=`date +"20%y-%m-%d"`
echo "DATE_STRING = $DATE_STRING"
# VERSION_LINE will be something like: '#define VERSION_STRING "1.2p2"'
VERSION_LINE=`grep "^#define VERSION_STRING" ../version.hpp`
#  - awk pulls the "1.2p2"
#  - tr deletes the surrounding quotes
VERSION_STRING=`echo "$VERSION_LINE" | awk '{ print $3 }' | tr -d '"'`
echo "VERSION_STRING = $VERSION_STRING"
echo "####### Creating Archive ###########"
BINARY_FILE="build${PLATFORM}-${VERSION_STRING}-${DATE_STRING}_CLXXXXXXXX.zip"
echo "BINARY_FILE is $BINARY_FILE"
```

The output is

```
PLATFORM = Linux64
DATE_STRING = 2015-10-31
VERSION_STRING = 1.2p2
####### Creating Archive ###########
-2015-10-31_CLXXXXXXXX.zip4-1.2p2
```

All the inputs to the expansion of BINARY_FILE look right to me, but the result is mucked up. I've run into this several years ago, but can never recall what causes it. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: i would guess it is a return character in your `$VERSION_LINE` pulled out of `.hpp` by `grep`. run `./yourscript | sed -n l`

Comment: Wouldn't awk extract just my field?

Comment: dunno. is there a `\r`eturn at the end of the line? is the field at the end of the line? even if im wrong about where it comes from or what it is, there is almost definitely something non-printable in there mucking about with the terminal display. run that command above to get a feel for what it is. by the way, it could very well be `echo` screwing with your output as well. a UNIX-standards-compliant `echo` will interpret C-style escapes in its arguments.

Comment: Yep. Right on. It was a \r somewhere the string. Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it? (Cut and past the above with "there is most likely ... )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is almost definitely something non-printable in there mucking about with the terminal display, and I have a hunch it is a `\r`eturn character fetched out of *`../version.hpp`* by `grep` into `$VERSION_LINE` and from thence by `awk` into `$VERSION_STRING`. I could be wrong, but you should [run](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154516/52934):

```
./yourscript | sed -n l
```

...to get a feel for whatever it is.

By the way, it could very well be `echo` screwing with your output as well. A UNIX-standards-compliant `echo` will [interpret C-style escapes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/219274/52934) in its arguments.

Comment: piping to `cat -v` or `cat -A` is a good way of finding carriage-returns and other control-codes in output.

Comment: @cas - possibly, but `sed -n l` is at least as good, and it is portable.

Comment: `cat -A` is GNU.  cat `-v` and `-t` are portable.

Comment: @cas - to linux and some bsds, yeah, probably. `sed`'s `l` is POSIX. the only option POSIX spec's for `cat` is `-u`. another nice thing about it is the *output format* is also reliably specified.

Comment: @BinaryZebra - that doesn't give you a line-by-line view, exactly. also, without `-v` it squeezes consecutive sequences of input. and i dunno why you would do hex to find a `\r`eturn or other non-printable: `od -vtc <in`. anyway, both `sed` and `od` are discussed in the linked answer.

Comment: @BinaryZebra - well, you definitely need an address if you don't use `-v` because otherwise there is no way of knowing how much input is squeezed for each `*` - which is specified behavior according to POSIX. `printf %0512s | od`. and even w/ `-v`, considering a conformant `od` writes output at 16-bytes *(or some multiple thereof)* per line rather than on a line-by-line basis it can be very easy to lose track of how its output relates to input anyway, and so an address is equally useful. still, if you like hex: `od -vtc -vtx1` will do both simultaneously - which is also a reason for an address

Comment: That is what I wrote: `od -tcx1`. For short strings works fine: `printf "hello" | od -tcx1`. Adding a `-v` makes it `printf "hello" | od -vtcx1`. The adress could be removed (if needed). But again, all that is POSIX valid.

Comment: @BinaryZebra - except you need a `-t` for each, i think. i could be wrong.