# Saving Output In a Variable and Re-using it

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
page=`grep $x /var/www/vhosts/example.com/statistics/logs/access_log | awk '{print $7}'| sort |uniq -c |sort -nr`
times=`$page | wc -l`
```

I am trying to save output of grep in a variable as `page`.

But later I want to re-use that grep output to calculate some other thing.

Below code throws:

```
command not found
```

How can I fix the issue and reuse the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `page` variable can contain arbitrary text, [you shouldn't use `echo`, you should use `printf`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/135943).

```
times="$(printf %s\\n "$page" | wc -l)"
```

Also note that if you have more than one trailing newline in the output of your `grep` command, you won't get the expected result no matter what, because [command substitution strips trailing newlines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17747/135943) and the `echo` command or the `printf` command I use alike will add in exactly *one* trailing newline, regardless of how many were stripped from the `grep` output when the `$page` variable was being set.

---

Of course, even in this case the `$times` variable will contain a bunch of extra spaces at the start, because that's how `wc -l` will output its information.  So this answer doesn't address the broader issue with your script: It looks like you are pressing `bash` into service where `awk` would serve better.

I could be wrong about that, depending on what you intend to do with the `$times` variable, but I seriously doubt it.  Most likely you can do what you need (*all* of what you need) with an `awk` one-liner.

Comment: I repeatedly recommend that all shell variable references (including `$(…)`) should be quoted (e.g., `times="$(printf "%s\n" "$page" | wc -l)"`), unless there is a good reason not to.  This is one of those special cases: since `wc` is fairly well behaved (except for its annoying habit of writing leading spaces), I recommend using `times=$(printf "%s\n" "$page" | wc -l)` (or, for example, `num_lines=$(wc -l < "filename")`) to get the shell to strip the spaces.

Comment: @G-Man, unfortunately that won't make any difference here.  The double quotes around the variable don't actually do anything on the Right Hand Side of an assignment (though [the rules with `export` are sometimes different](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97569/135943)); the shell won't word split the RHS regardless of quoting.  So you'd still have the extra spaces.  You could avoid the issue by leaving `$times` unquoted when it is used later, however.

Comment: True. Anyway, the question here is a dupe (I can't find the other one right now...) but for the record you can also use herestrings/heredocs if you want to reuse the output saved into a variable. Also, fwiw, in this particular case there should be no trailing empty lines.

Comment: @Wildcard Thank you very much for your answer. I have a boolean issue with this same manner. `whois=\`whois 100.43.81.149\`; bool="$(printf %s\\n "$whois" | grep -q netname:)" ; if $bool;then:fi` bool variable is always true although in this case it is not. Would you help please?

Comment: @NecNecco, please post a new question.  (I will mention, though, that `if` takes a *command*, not a variable.)

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275738/boolean-issue-for-grep

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:** Revision for multi-line $page values, thanks @Wildcard!

You were very close on line 2. As long as your line 1 actually works, then for your second line you should try:

```bash
times="$(echo "$page" | wc -l)"
```

### Explanation

- `$(` and `)` is command substitution, equivalent to were doing with the backticks, (in `man bash` these are referred to as `backquotes`), but I prefer `$(` `)` because they are easier to spot in code
- Just having `$page` will not pass anything to `wc -l`
- Bash will instead think you want to run whatever is written in `$page` as a command and then passing that command's output to `wc -l`, so if `$page` contains `5 bla` it will think `5 bla` is a command. This would lead to errors such as those you found when you saw `command not found`
- So to pass the value we can `echo` the `$page` variable
- However if `$page` contains multi-line values, `echo $page` will by default result in losing those lines, they just become spaces
- To avoid this undesired result, preserve the value and those new lines in `$page` by surrounding with quotes: `echo "$page"`

So, by using `echo "$page"`, `wc -l` is then able to correctly receive `$page`'s value.

Comment: This won't actually work without quoting `"$page"`.  It will *always* output "1".  A newline is just a form of whitespace, and `echo` won't preserve it.  (Actually, `echo` won't even *see* the newline.)

Comment: Good point, thanks @Wildcard, answer updated to include quoting  "$page"