# Boolean Issue for Grep

Tags: grep

```
        whois=`whois 100.43.81.149`
        bool="$(printf %s\\n "$whois" | grep -q netname:)"
        if $bool;
            then
                echo "netname: is available"    
            else
                echo "netname: is not available"            
        fi
```

I am trying to save `whois` command information at `whois` variable.
Then on that variable I am searching `netname:` string and saving the result at `bool` variable.

But somehow the `bool` variable always enters `true` case, although it should not be in this context.

What might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two main problems here:

- `$(` takes standard output from a command, not its exit code;
- `if $bool` checks if a command with the name matching the data in `$bool` returns 0, not if the bool is 0 or 1. That is, if `$bool` contained "foo", the command "foo" would be executed.

Just do the check directly:

```
if whois 100.43.81.149 | grep -q netname:; then
    ...
fi
```

If you must store the exit code instead of just doing it directly, use `[ -eq ,.. ]`, or the non-POSIX `((`:

```
whois 100.43.81.149 | grep -q netname:
netname_exists=$?

if (( netname_exists == 0 )); then  # Non-POSIX
if [ "$netname_exists" -eq 0 ]; then  # POSIX
```

If you must store the output from `whois` for later use too, you can do this:

```
whois_data=$(whois 100.43.81.149)
printf '%s\n' "$whois_data" | grep -q netname:  # or use <<< (non-POSIX) or <<
netname_exists=$?
```

Comment: Or `whois 100.43.81.149 | grep -q netname:; netname_exists=$?` (to save a subshell).  Storing return values is pretty desperate once-in-a-career kind of stuff...

Comment: Thanks Chris, I can directly use whois command in conditional but I want to decrease number of whois queries. Therefore I save the result of whois query in variable and use it in the script many times. I thought "grep -q" would return true or false and I can use it. So if I can keep the code structure  like my example but without increasing whois queries, it will be great.

Comment: @NecNecco In which case, just store the output of `whois` first and then direct (with `printf` + pipe, `<<`, or the non-standard `<<<`) the output into `grep -q`.

Comment: Chris, sound great. But could not forge the code myself. Would you mind posting your code as my example please? I will accept your answer.

Comment: @NecNecco I've appended code to that effect in the answer.

Comment: Thanks Chris. What exactly `$?` does?

Comment: @NecNecco It contains the exit code from the last command of the last pipeline.