# Inconsistent shell behavior involving endline characters

Tags: shell-script, printf

Why does:

```
[ "a" != "$(printf "\na")" ] && echo true || echo false
```

print `true` while:

```
[ "a" != "$(printf "\n")a" ] && echo true || echo false
```

print `false`?

Comment: [Why does shell Command Substitution gobble up a trailing newline char?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17747/why-does-shell-command-substitution-gobble-up-a-trailing-newline-char) (and [some others](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=command+substitution+newline) about the same thing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because `$(...)`. That substitution automatically remove ending newline character. That's a good default behaviour.