# Reading from a text file and printing the words character by character at a time

Tags: shell, text-processing

I would like to write a program that reads from a text file and prints in `Terminal` the words of that file character by character every one second.

For example, in a text file `log.txt` let's say I have this sentence:

```
I love Unix but I don't know programming.
```

I would like the code to read the previous sentence and print the letters, the spaces one by one every second.

Answer (score 9):

[Goro's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/467768/85039) will work, but it should be noted that [command substitution removes trailing newlines as specified by POSIX standard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/17762/85039).  Thus it may not be desirable where you want to actually iterate over *all* charactes, even non-printable ones. Another issue is that C-style for loop is used in bash and ksh93, but not in standard (aka POSIX-comliant ) `/bin/sh`. The `${variable:index:offset}` form of parameter expansion is also type of [bashism](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) and not specified by [POSIX definitions of parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) (though supported by `ksh93` and `zsh`).

Nonetheless, there's a way to iterate over all characters in file portably and in a [far more practical way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/85039). That's to use `awk`:

```bsh
# all characters on the same line
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=length;i++){ printf "%c",substr($0,i,1); system("sleep 1");}; print}' input.txt

# all characters on separate lines
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=length;i++){ print substr($0, i, 1); system("sleep 1"); }}' input.txt
```

With this command `substr()` and `system()` are both specified in [POSIX awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html) and will in fact iterate over all characters.

Comment: @Goro Already added a comment about that, see the edit

Comment: @don_crissti I need to find a better phrase than "bashism" because I always get `ksh` and `zsh` mentioned. Can we start using something like `{ba,k,z}sh` maybe ? :)

Comment: I think just mentioning non-posix or non-standard would do...

Comment: @don_crissti  non-posix adds another level of ambiguity because POSIX mostly was based on `ksh`  and Bourne shell, and bash has `--posix` flag and supoorts most of the POSIX features. Idk, there's gotta be a better way to phrase it

Comment: I don't find it ambiguous tbh... Also, you seem to be contradicting yourself:  your answer says "_not specified by POSIX_" but you're saying that using "_non-posix_" is ambiguous... How is "_non-posix_" different than "_not specified by POSIX_" ? Anyway, feel free to use any term/phrase you find appropriate, my point was against _bashism_ - which is the wrong term considering the fact that `bash` copied a lot from `ksh` (and even `zsh); most features that some people call _bashisms_ have originated in other shells (and, obviously, are supported in those shells too).

Answer (score 3):

You can do this

```
var=$(cat log.txt)
for (( i=0; i<${#var}; i++ )); do
 sleep 1 | echo -ne "${var:$i:1}"
done
echo ""
```

Comment: thk for quick answr. this is wht i want but why it priunt on the same line ike this `I love Unix but I don't know programming.[zahi@sonar]$, how print on separate line?

Comment: Ah, please see my revisions

Answer (score 3):

With `bash` or `ksh93` you can read single characters using the shell's built-in `read` command:

```
while IFS= read -r -n 1 c; do 
  printf '%c' "$c"
  sleep 1
done < log.txt
printf '\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Python solution:

```
python -c "from time import sleep
with open('/tmp/file.txt') as f:
 for line in f:
  for c in line:
   print(c, end='', flush=True);sleep(1);"
```

You should just be able to paste that on the command line and change the name of the input file.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `Perl` as shown:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{$/=\1;$|=1;} sleep 1' log.txt
```

- `-p` will autoprint the current record before fetching the next.
- `$/=\1` will make `perl` read the input stream a byte at a time, and assuming the characters are a byte sized.
- `$|=1` will output is buffered.