# When printing a variable that contains newlines, why is the last newline stripped?

Tags: shell, command-substitution, newlines

Contents of file.txt (no weirdness, text file as defined by POSIX)

```
iguana
gecko
anole
```

Sample script:

```
#!/bin/sh

string="$(cat file.txt)"

printf '%s' "$string"
```

Sample output:

```
[coolguy@somemachine ~]$ ./script.sh
iguana
gecko
anole[coolguy@somemachine ~]$
```

What happened to the last newline? Why are all are newlines except the last one preserved? It seems like we shouldn't have to use echo to add a newline if there should already be one there.

Comment: @Jesse_b - according to POSIX _"a text file, contains characters organized into one or more lines"_ and _"a line is a sequence of zero or more non-newline characters plus a terminating newline character."_

Comment: Effectively dupe https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17747/why-does-shell-command-substitution-gobble-up-a-trailing-newline-char and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17732/where-has-the-trailing-newline-char-gone-from-my-command-substitution

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Should I delete it?

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that, for the same design rationale, here-string redirections add a newline at the end of the string provided, like in `cat <<< foo`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's not the printing, it's the command substitution that does that. It's defined to do that. From the [POSIX description](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03):

> The shell shall expand the command substitution by executing command in a subshell environment  and replacing the command substitution  with the standard output of the command, **removing sequences of one or more {newline} characters at the end of the substitution**.

Note that it removes *all* trailing newlines, not just one.

In a somewhat common case, you'd use command substitution to capture a one-line output, say `osrev=$(uname -r)`. The utilities usually print a trailing newline, for user convenience on the command line. But in a shell script, you might want to use that string as part of another one, say a filename: `filename=blahblah-$osrev.dat`. And in that case, the trailing newline would only be a nuisance.

And of course, a plain `echo` will add a final newline in any case.

---

If you want the contents of the file as-is in the variable, then the common workaround is to add an extra character in the command substitution, and remove that later:

```
printf "foo\nbar\n\n" > file
string=$(cat file; echo x)
string=${string%x}
printf '%q\n' "$string"
```

that outputs `$'foo\nbar\n\n'`, showing both trailing newlines present.

---

Depending on what you intend to do with the data, there may be other ways. E.g. a `while read` loop, or Bash's `mapfile`, if you happen to want to process the file line-by-line.

Comment: This question has been marked as a duplicate. Is it good practice to delete a question after it has been marked as such?

Comment: @HaroldFischer, there's a whole bunch of questions marked duplicates on the site, so no, not really. And I don't think you even could delete it, since there's an upvoted answer. See [deleted-questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions).